# Error visualizing the attention maps for an attention model trained in Tensorflow Keras

Tags: image, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, attention-model

I am trying to reproduce the notebook at https://www.kaggle.com/kmader/cardiomegaly-pretrained-vgg16/notebook to train a VGG-16 model with attention. The model architecture and training are exactly as discussed in the notebook. I am able to train and save the attention model weights. The error occurs when trying to visualize the attention maps using the trained model.

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
attn_func = K.function(inputs = [attn_model.get_input_at(0), 
                                 K.learning_phase()],
           outputs = [attn_layer.get_output_at(0)]
          )
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: Input tensors to a Functional must come from `tf.keras.Input`. Received: 0 (missing previous layer metadata).
```

I am using Tensorflow version `2.6.2`. The notebook using Tensorflow `1. x` version.

Comment: Hello @Shiva, I and Dr. K. Mader have been working on this problem for a conf and will release the code soon. We used tf 1.x primarily. Have you successfully run the code in tf 1.x?

Comment: @M.Innat: It works fine with Tensorflow 1.x. However, the attention was all over the place and does not confirm to the expert knowledge of the problem. Do you modify the number of convolutional layers in the attention model or optimize it by some means?

Comment: yes, modification is needed.

Comment: @M.Innat Instead of creating a sequential model using the base_pretrained_model and the attention model that considers each model as a layer, I would like to access the individual layers of the base_pretrained_model and attention model while creating the combined model. How do I modify these lines?

from keras.models import Sequential
tb_model = Sequential(name = 'combined_model')
base_pretrained_model.trainable = True
tb_model.add(base_pretrained_model)
tb_model.add(attn_model)
tb_model.summary()

Comment: @M.Innat Basically, in addition to seeing the attention map, I would also like to visualize the features in the block5_conv3 layer of the base_pretrained_model. But the sequential model considers the base_pretrained_model as a layer. So, instead of creating a sequential model, I would prefer to construct a functional model to load all the layers of the base_pretrained_model and the attention model.

Comment: Yes, you need functinal api to build the network in that case. https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/